# How can I change the columns in contact page on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, frontend, contact-us

I would like to set 2 columns right to my contact page **using XML** on my specific theme.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a file like that below.

```
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/MY_CUSTOM_THEME/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml
```

With that content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any need to copy the contents of `contact_index_index.xml` over when you can extend it.

To do this just create this file in your theme:

```
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/MY_CUSTOM_THEME/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml
```

And add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-right" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

I don't have time to try it but I imagine this works.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer